# A variation on the projective Nullstellensatz

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, computational-geometry, projective-varieties

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space, and let $f_1,\dots,f_n \in S^d(V^*)$ be homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ for which $V(f_1,\dots, f_n)=\{0\}$.

Must there exist a positive integer $k\geq d$ such that for all $v \in S^k(V^*)$ there exists $g_1,\dots, g_n \in S^{k-d}(V^*)$ for which $v=\sum_{i=1}^n g_i f_i$?

I am inclined to guess that this is true, based on the projective Nullstellensatz, which tells us that for any finite set of linear forms $L=\{l_1,\dots, l_m\}$ that spans $V^*$, there exists a positive integer $k\geq d$ such that for all $l\in L$ there exists $g_1,\dots, g_n \in S^{k-d}(V^*)$ for which $l^k=\sum_{i=1}^n g_i f_i$.

Comment: This is the usual Nullstellensatz.

Comment: Is it? Now I don't think it is true -- Isn't it equivalent to saying that $f_1,\dots, f_n$ cut out $\{0\}$ scheme-theoretically, which may not always be the case?

Comment: No, see my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I must be misunderstanding what it means to cut out a variety scheme-theoretically.

Comment: If it were true for all homogeneous polynomials of degree $\geq 1$, and not just all homogeneous polynomials of degree $\geq k$, that would be scheme-theoretic.

Comment: I thought scheme-theoretic meant that there exists $k$ for which $<f_1,...,f_n>_{k'}=I(\{0\})_{k'}=S^{k'}(V^*)$ for all $k' \geq k$. I will have to stare at it more...

Comment: I'm using the version for affine schemes. Maybe you're thinking of projective schemes? In that case, the condition you gave beginning with "Must .. " in your post is equivalent to $f_1,\dots, f_n$ cutting out the empty set (scheme-theoretically or set-theoretically, as these are equivalent in the empty set case).

Comment: Ah yes, the world makes sense again. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $V(f_1,\dots,f_n)=0$, by the Nullestellensatz
$$ \sqrt{ (f_1,\dots, f_n)} = I ( V( f_1,\dots, f_n)) = I(0) = (x_1,\dots, x_r)$$
where $x_1,\dots, x_r$ are a basis for $V^*$.

So for each $i$ from $1$ to $r$, $x_i^{e_i} \in (f_1,\dots, f_n)$ for some $e_i \in \mathbb N$.

It follows that $$(x_1,\dots,x_r)^{\sum_{i=1}^n e_i} \subseteq (f_1,\dots, f_n) $$ as each monomial in $(x_1,\dots,x_r)^{\sum_{i=1}^r e_i}$ is a multiple of $x_i^{e_i}$ for some $i$. (In fact, we can subtract $r-1$ from the exponent if desired).

So taking $k =\sum_{i=1}^r e_i$, for $n \geq k$, and $v$ homogeneous of degree $n$, we have  $v\in (x_1,\dots,x_r)^n \subseteq (x_1,\dots,x_r)^k$, so $v = \sum_{i=1}^n g_i v_i$, and we can take the degree $n-k$ part of each $g_i$.